# signal handler and library worker threads

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, signals

The client code of my application is single-threaded, but I'm using a TCP socket communication library that *might* create worker threads that should be transparent from the point of view of the client application. However, I had a signal handler for catching SIGSEGV errors that tries to print a stack trace, that is now intermittently failing.

I'm wondering if it is possible that the fact that worker threads are being created inside the process could be affecting the signal handler execution? can the kernel decide to execute the signal handler inside some of the worker threads? and if it is so, is there some way to avoid that from happening and force the signal handler to execute always on the main process thread?

Comment: Did you read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

1. `SIGSEGV` handlers have an inherent problem, which that as every `SEGV` (contrived examples aside) arise from undefined behaviour (to say nothing of unexpected behaviour), what the program does afterwards is equally undefined. Or in less language-lawyerese terms, you don't know what's broken. If you've overwritten the heap, for instance, or you `SEGV` whilst some lock within `malloc()` is held, your signal handler isn't going to work.
2. Getting threads and signal handlers to work together is not, at the best of times, easy. Programs are far less tolerant of errors in signal set up when threaded (in my experience). Firstly, makes sure you are using a modern API. IE do not use `signal (2)`. Use `sigaction` and `pthread_sigmask` appropriately.
3. Note that some signals (including `SIGSEGV`) are delivered to the process and not to the thread.